# How to reference new DynamoDB record in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to reference a newly created DynamoDB record in AWS Lambda? For example, retrieving and using the ID of the newly created record. Hoping this is possible without a query to retrieve the new record from DynamoDB.

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

... // Omitting the rest of the code in this example

const params = {
  TableName : 'ExampleTableName',
  Item: {
    id: uuid.v1()
  }
}
  
try {
  await docClient.put(params).promise();
} catch (err) {
  return err;
}

// Reference newly created record to retrieve the ID.
```

Comment: You generated the UUID client-side so why do you need it returned back?

Comment: To ensure that it is only referenced after it is done being created.

Comment: Maybe you can explain more. This doesn't make sense to me yet.

Comment: Added an answer, did it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can achieve it using `ReturnValues` Paramter.

ReturnValues:- return the item's attribute values in the same operation.

But I am afraid that if you want to achieve your purpose you need to use an alternative API which [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)

From the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax)

> Use ReturnValues if you want to get the item attributes as they appear before or after they are updated. For UpdateItem, the valid values are:

> NONE - If ReturnValues is not specified, or if its value is NONE, then nothing is returned. (This setting is the default for ReturnValues.)

> ALL_OLD - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appeared before the UpdateItem operation.

> UPDATED_OLD - Returns only the updated attributes, as they appeared before the UpdateItem operation.

> ALL_NEW - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appear after the UpdateItem operation.

> UPDATED_NEW - Returns only the updated attributes, as they appear after the UpdateItem operation.

There is no additional cost associated with requesting a return value aside from the small network and processing overhead of receiving a larger response. No read capacity units are consumed.
The values returned are strongly consistent.

Why you can use returnValue with putItem? Reason -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#API_PutItem_RequestSyntax which wont solve your purpose.

```
You can store return values in variable and add custom logic to proceed further. :)
```